# apt-get update error on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, unity, upgrade, package-management, dpkg

I have a big problem with apt-get update. Here is my error when I type`sudo apt-get update`

```
 thee@miller:~$ sudo apt-get update
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease                                  
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease                              
Ign http://dl.google.com stable InRelease                                      
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg                                
Ign http://archive.canonical.com trusty InRelease                              
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease [65.9 kB]          
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg                                    
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release                                    
Get:2 http://archive.canonical.com trusty Release.gpg [933 B]                  
Get:3 http://archive.canonical.com trusty Release [9,359 B]                    
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release                                        
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources                               
Get:4 http://archive.canonical.com trusty/partner Sources [10.0 kB]            
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Get:5 http://archive.canonical.com trusty/partner amd64 Packages [5,601 B]     
Hit http://dl.google.com stable/main amd64 Packages                            
Get:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease [65.9 kB]         
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Get:7 http://archive.canonical.com trusty/partner i386 Packages [6,278 B]      
Get:8 ftp://ftp.videolan.org ./ InRelease                                      
Get:9 http://archive.canonical.com trusty/partner Translation-en [4,593 B]     
Get:10 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed InRelease [65.9 kB]        
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Ign ftp://ftp.videolan.org ./ InRelease                                        
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports InRelease                    
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit ftp://ftp.videolan.org ./ Release.gpg                                      
Get:11 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg [933 B]                 
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Get:12 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Sources [7,126 B]
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit ftp://ftp.videolan.org ./ Release                                          
Get:13 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Sources [164 kB]   
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en_US                     
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit ftp://ftp.videolan.org ./ Packages                                         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Get:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease [15.4 kB]                     
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en_US                         
Get:15 ftp://ftp.videolan.org ./ Translation-en_US                             
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en                            
Get:16 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Sources [381 kB]       
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Get:17 ftp://ftp.videolan.org ./ Translation-en                                
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                                
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                                
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                                
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Sources                               
Get:18 ftp://ftp.videolan.org ./ Translation-en_US                             
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Sources                               
Get:19 ftp://ftp.videolan.org ./ Translation-en                                
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Sources                               
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Get:20 ftp://ftp.videolan.org ./ Translation-en_US                             
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Sources                               
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Get:21 ftp://ftp.videolan.org ./ Translation-en                                
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Get:22 ftp://ftp.videolan.org ./ Translation-en_US                             
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Sources                               
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Get:23 ftp://ftp.videolan.org ./ Translation-en                                
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Get:24 http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Sources [14 B]                     
Get:25 http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages [664 B]             
Get:26 http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages [664 B]              
Get:27 ftp://ftp.videolan.org ./ Translation-en_US                             
Get:28 http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en [410 B]             
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Sources                               
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Ign ftp://ftp.videolan.org ./ Translation-en_US                                
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Get:29 ftp://ftp.videolan.org ./ Translation-en                                
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Sources                               
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Err ftp://ftp.videolan.org ./ Translation-en                                   
  Unable to fetch file, server said 'No transfer timeout (60 seconds): closing control connection  ' [IP: 88.191.250.2 21]
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Sources                               
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Sources                               
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                                    
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                                    
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                                    
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Sources                               
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Sources                               
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Sources                               
  404  Not Found
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
  404  Not Found
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
  404  Not Found
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en_US                     
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Get:30 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Sources [5,360 B]
Get:31 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages [893 kB]
Get:32 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [15.9 kB]
Get:33 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages [14.8 kB]
Get:34 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe amd64 Packages [374 kB]
Get:35 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main i386 Packages [855 kB] 
Get:36 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted i386 Packages [15.6 kB]
Get:37 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse i386 Packages [15.2 kB]
Get:38 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe i386 Packages [375 kB]
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Translation-en            
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Translation-en      
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Translation-en      
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Translation-en        
Get:39 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/universe Sources [17.0 kB] 
Get:40 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/restricted Sources [28 B]  
Get:41 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/main Sources [119 kB]      
Get:42 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/multiverse Sources [28 B]  
Get:43 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/universe amd64 Packages [12.6 kB]
Get:44 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/restricted amd64 Packages [28 B]
Get:45 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/main amd64 Packages [104 kB]
Get:46 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/multiverse amd64 Packages [28 B]
Get:47 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/universe i386 Packages [12.6 kB]
Get:48 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/restricted i386 Packages [28 B]
Get:49 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/main i386 Packages [100 kB]
Get:50 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/multiverse i386 Packages [28 B]
Get:51 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/main Translation-en [37.2 kB]
Get:52 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/multiverse Translation-en [28 B]
Get:53 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/restricted Translation-en [28 B]
Get:54 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/universe Translation-en [14.1 kB]
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Sources             
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Sources           
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Sources                 
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse Sources           
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe amd64 Packages      
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted amd64 Packages    
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main amd64 Packages          
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages    
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe i386 Packages       
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted i386 Packages     
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main i386 Packages           
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse i386 Packages     
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Translation-en          
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse Translation-en    
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Translation-en    
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Translation-en      
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release                                
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Sources                     
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Sources                       
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources                           
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Sources                     
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main amd64 Packages                    
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted amd64 Packages              
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse amd64 Packages              
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe amd64 Packages                
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main i386 Packages                     
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted i386 Packages               
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse i386 Packages               
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe i386 Packages                 
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en                    
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en              
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en              
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en                
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en_US                 
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en_US           
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en_US           
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en_US             
Fetched 3,785 kB in 5min 30s (11.5 kB/s)                                       
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/InRelease  Unable to find expected entry 'm/source/Sources' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

W: Failed to fetch ftp://ftp.videolan.org/pub/debian/stable/./en  Unable to fetch file, server said 'No transfer timeout (60 seconds): closing control connection  ' [IP: 88.191.250.2 21]

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/libv4l/ppa/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/libv4l/ppa/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/libv4l/ppa/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
thee@miller:~$
```

Here is a the look of my resources file:

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20160217.1)]/ trusty main restricted
# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution. deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted
multiverse deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty
multiverse universe main restricted #Added by software-properties

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution. deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted multiverse deb-src
http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse
universe main restricted #Added by software-properties

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team. deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe deb
http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.

deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security main
restricted multiverse deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
trusty-security m

#deb http: //ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packagesultiverse universe main restricted #Added by software-properties deb
http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security universe

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users. deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner deb-src
http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software. deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main deb-src
http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main deb
http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-proposed universe
restricted main multiverse deb-src
http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-proposed universe
restricted main multiverse #Added by software-properties deb
http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports universe
restricted main multiverse deb-src
http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports universe
restricted main multiverse #Added by software-properties
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty universe
```

I am sorry I posted the file in that format...I haven't earned enough reputation to post the file itself. I have already tried these commands
.

```
 sudo apt-get -f install

 sudo apt-get update

 sudo apt-get upgrade

 sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

 sudo apt-get autoremove

 sudo apt-get autoclean

 sudo apt-get clean
```

I have also tried to install this

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
```

which did not install. Instead it said

```
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
```

`mysql server` is very ok. I have even listed the ppa I have but I wont see the one that brings this trouble. I have tried many other stuff. Please someone, save my canoe before I drown

Comment: Try to run sudo apt-get -f install , that will try to fix broken dependencies

Comment: I already tried that...up there..Am sorry maybe you didn't see. It was almost the first thing I did and I got this E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your`sources.list` file seems to be corrupt. An example `sources.list` is shared below. You can replace the contents of your `sources.list` with the example.

1. Open your current `sources.list`:

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
   ```
2. Either rectify the lines that produces the error or just copy from the example and replace the contents of your `sources.list` with it.
3. Next, from the keyboard press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>, then <kbd>Enter</kbd> and finally <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>.

---

Example `sources.list`:

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted universe multiverse 
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security main restricted universe multiverse 
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted universe multiverse 
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-proposed main restricted universe multiverse 
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse 
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security main restricted universe multiverse 
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted universe multiverse 
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-proposed main restricted universe multiverse 
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
```

[sources.list generator](https://repogen.simplylinux.ch/)

---

Also, to remove the left-over errors, first check all the `ppas` currently installed in your system:

```
ls -l /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
```

Remove the `ppas` that are causing the error by deleting the corresponding `*.list` file. Do not worry as you can re-add these `ppas` at a later point of time using `sudo add-apt-repository`.

Now, update your sources using:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

---

There are [better ways](http://www.askubuntu.com/questions/307/how-can-ppas-be-removed) to remove ppas. Since you are unable to install `ppa-purge`, therefore, I suggested the above method.

Comment: Thanks..that worked...Not exactly your way but through you I got the solution. Went to software updates, clicked on other software, unchecked the erroneous PPAs, (three of them) used this this  ---> ls -l /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ to show the leftovers then purged them. I then cleaned --->  sudo apt-get autoclean and then did sudo apt-get update...I then smiled because everything was sorted.